# Software to summarize content of an ebook?

Tags: ebooks

I am reading an ebook and I am looking for a software that summarizes the content of an ebook, so that I read only important content!! Is there any good software like this? By the Way I'm reading [a technical ebook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568817207).

Comment: The tricky bit is *what* is "important" - **you** may already know 80% of the content but **which** 80% and how is any software to know - some technical books do provide a precis at the beginning, or event tests at the end, of each chapter.

Comment: @SteveBarnes same thing I always wondering. But obviously, [it is possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization), and [solutions are available](https://www.google.com/search?q=software+to+summarize+text+content). **Inder Gill:** have you tried a Google search first (just follow the last link I gave) and checked some of the results? Did any of those work for you, or what were you missing?

Answer (score 1):

As I was searching the web, I found that [nice link on CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41036/intelligent-software-to-summarize-content-of-an-ebook). Comments say that it would be really hard and long to achieve it. They said it would be "science fiction for today".

I guess you're aware of [smmry.com](http://smmry.com/), it's an online tool for your purpose. However, it can just summarize online articles and pdfs. The online article function is good, it summarized the test articles I used. The pdf function didn't work for me at all, I always got an error.

Actually, there are tons of software like smmry. But I think the guys at CS.SE got it straight: It simply isn't possible right now to summarize an ebook. At least you could try to convert it into a pdf and try out sites like smmry.com or [freesumarizer.com](http://freesummarizer.com/).